# Why is a still 0 after that operation?

Tags: java

Why is `a` still `0` after the following operation?

```
int a = 0;
a+=a++;
```

Comment: Google postfix and prefix increment operators.If you want 1 ,then do `a+=++a`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a++` increments `a` but returns its previous value `0`.

That's why `a+=a++`, which is equivalent to `a=a+a++`, sets `a` back to `0+0`;